# Elementor text editor style glitch

Tags: wordpress, elementor

So when i try to make my text bold, italic or want a stripe under my text inside the elementor text editor, it doenst work. If i click on bold it goes bold for 5 ms and then back on normal, it just flashes or something.

- I tried it in icongito chrome.
- I tried reinstalling elementor free and Pro.
- I tried to downgrade the elementor versions

Comment: inspect your element, and look under "computed" - there you can see if your font-weight, style or decoration is overwritten by some CSS somewhere. click on it, and you can see where that css rule is located.

Comment: As far as i can see nothing is overwritten... Do you have any other possible solutions?